# iOS swift 3.0 local JSON parsing crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift3

I am using a local JSON in my swift projects. I need to extract the data in array. I am getting an unexpected crash.

My JSON is:

```
{
cueca =     (
             {
             agentName = "Sant";
             applicationName = "Get CDR Avaya";
             body = "Detail of the message.";
             imageType = 1;
             messageType = 1;
             requestTime = "2016-01-01 00:00:04";
             sendTime = "2016-01-01 00:00:04";
             subject = "Mensagem 05";
             },
             {
             agentName = "Sant2";
             applicationName = "Script Programming2";
             body = "Detail of the message.";
             imageType = 1;
             messageType = 1;
             requestTime = "2016-01-01 00:00:03";
             sendTime = "2016-01-01 00:00:03";
             subject = "Mensagem 04";
             }
);
}
```

MY code is:

```
    let file = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ABC", ofType: "json")! as NSString
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: file as String)
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
```

My issue is:

> fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No string key for value in object around character 6." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No string key for value in object around character 6.}: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-800.0.46.2/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 178

I need to get all the object inside "cuaca" that i can use the array for further use.

Comment: it means is not a valid json , check once your JSON file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally its a valid `json` data issue if you are getting json data from server or from anywhere else just try to rectify the faults while creating `json` nods, whereas in your data you have `cueca` object with array of 2 agent record.

Valid `JSON` example:

```
{
    "cueca": [{
        "agentName": "Sant",
        // data so on
    }, {
        "agentName": "Sant2",
        // data so on
    }]
}
```

Here dictionary `cueca` containing an  **[ ] array** of record.

Answer (score 1):

Crash is because file path is nil or url is nil or data is nil. Please add nil check. Try following code

```
 if let file:String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ABC", ofType: "json")
        {
            if let url:URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: file)
            {
                if let data:NSData = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL)
                {
                    do{
                      _ = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions())
                    }catch{
                        print(error)
                    }

                }

            }

        }
```